# In developer edition how to check Manage License available for a installed package?

Tags: licenses, userlicense, installedpackage

We are doing a POC, any option to test 'manage license' in developer edition. Tried installing different apps from App-exchange like, Account hierarchy, CTU, Agile accelerator, Test generator, etc. Can't see the option 'Manage license' and also when we query  UserPackageLicense object, count returned is zero for this installed package. Even if it's installed only for admin's, by default all user get the managed package access for this free apps.

We want to assign license through apex code, by copying it from a existing user to newly created user. For testing this license should be available for an free installed package.

Unless it is a paid it's not a licensed package? if so please help with a cheapest app i can go with just for testing above scenario.

Comment: For cheapest app you can look at appexchange. Did you try installing a trail version of any paid product?

Comment: Managed packages may be licensed or unlicensed, paid or free. Most likely, you're installing packages that are either Site-wide by default, or perhaps even in a trial mode, which is usually a Site license. Did you check Setup > Company Information to see when/if the package expires? I'm not sure you can actually pay for apps in a Developer org, so you probably can't test licenses that way.